# Schedule Apex SOQL To Update Field Question

Tags: apex

I am creating a scheduled apex class to update the number of contacts in a certain stage on an account. The issue I am running into is with my SOQL query

```
SELECT accountid accountId, count(Id) result from Contact where accountId != null AND Outreach_Status__c = 'Replied' GROUP BY accountId limit 200
```

When the outreach status of the contact no longer equals 'replied' then the SOQL query will not capture that there are 0 contacts on the account where the outreach status is replied.

I am probably thinking about this the wrong way and would love to see what others have in mind.

Comment: https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries

Comment: you can vote up https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873000000079UUAAY although SFDC doesn't seem keen on addressing it despite 17000+ votes. see also https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320379&type=1 (tho won't work on deletes)

Answer (score 0):

**If you choose not to use DLRS which I linked in the comments, you can try the following**

I have a few things I'd like to talk about on this.

I would probably not do this in scheduled Apex. I typically do this kind of work in triggers on the account.

Also, you are correct that the issue is in your soql query. Basically, since you are only pulling in records where the status is replied, you will not get an account Id if the account has no replied contacts. Because of this we can assume that if an account is not returned, the count should be 0.

I would do something that looks like:

```
public class without sharing AccountService {
    public static void rollupRepliedContacts(Map<Id, Account> newMap) {
        if (Trigger.NewMap != null) {
            Map<Id, Decimal> resultMap = new Map<Id, Decimal>();

            for (AggregateResult ar : [
                SELECT accountid accountId, count(Id) result
                FROM Contact 
                WHERE accountId IN :newMap.keySet()
            ]) {
                // This data structure is easier to work with then the results
                // of an aggregate query
                resultMap.put((Id) ar.get('accountid'), Decimal ar.get('result'));
            }

            for (Acount a : newMap.values()) {
                if (resultMap.containsKey(a.Id)) {
                    // Make sure to update only records that need to be updated
                    // This is less of a problem in a before trigger as these 
                    // changes do not cause another trigger execution but this is
                    // a good habit as it can prevent recursion in other triggers
                    if (a.CustomField__c != resultMap.get(a)) {
                        a.CustomField__c = resultMap.get(a);
                    }
                } else {
                    a.CustomField__c = 0;
                }
            }
        } // else this is not an update trigger
    }
}
```

Then your trigger would be:

```
switch on Trigger.operationType {
    when BEFORE_UPDATE {
        AccountService.rollupRepliedContacts(Trigger.newMap);
    }
}
```

Lastly, for your contacts:

```
public class ContactService {
    public static void rollupRepliedContacts(List<Contact> newContacts, Map<Id, Contact> oldContacts) {
        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

        for (Contact c : newContact) {
            if (
                c.OutreachStatus__c == 'Replied' && 
                oldContacts.get(c.Id).OutreachStatus__c != 'Replied'
            ) {
                accountsToUpdate.add(new Account(Id = c.AccountId));
            }
        }

        update accountsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

And the trigger

```
ContactService.rollupRepliedContacts(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
```

The reason I put the bulk of the work in the account trigger is because it will allow the roll-up to work even if the change does not come from the contacts. In your case, this is not super necessary but in my experience the pattern of having the object that has the roll-up field do the work makes this more reliable and reusable. You could move the code all into the contact trigger and it'd probably work just fine.

You'll also want to think about what happens when a contact is deleted (I can't do everything for you).

Comment: But how would me moving a contact record trigger an update on the account?

Comment: I updated the answer to give you some more to look at and think about. I'd like to repeat that the DLRS tool is probably best but if you can't/won't use it this is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's one of the common issues with coding your own rollups (how to detect when the last group of records fall off the rollup?)

This is one of the reasons why The Declarative Rollup Summary Tool is suggested, as I believe it can handle such situations.

If you're dead set on rolling your own though, then a fairly small and simple shift in your approach can work wonders.

As you've learned, counting the number of things related to another record only works as long as you have things to count on that related record.

Instead, I'd suggest focusing first on which `Contact` records are changing. Any `Account` related to a `Contact` record that has been changed needs to have its count re-calculated. Assume that the count for every `Account` that a changing `Contact` is related to should be 0, and then use your query with aggregate functions to prove otherwise. Using `WHERE AccountId IN :accountIdCollection` should help the selectivity of your query as well.

If your `Account` no longer has any `Contacts` to contribute to the count, it'll be updated to a count of 0, else, you'll get the most recent count. Just to be absolutely clear here, you do want to update *all* of the `Accounts` that you find here.

If, for some reason, that approach isn't workable, then re-calculating the count for *every `Account` that has a non-zero count* would also work (but doesn't scale as well).